# Can't install ATI drivers on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, 11.10

I can't install either of the two ATI drivers on Ubuntu 11.10. When I try,  I get the following error message:

> Sorry, installation of this driver failed.
>
> Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

That log file has too many words for me to write in this box (+11k).

Comment: and what is in `/var/log/jockey.log` ?

Comment: To many word for me to write in this box :< +11k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem, as everyone I guess.

(I had this message but the driver has been installed anyway, check if you have amd catalyst in your appication, the driver could be installed.)

What is sure is that the installation of the second driver which is proposed works (not the updated one)
If you want the latest driver, you can also download id from amd, the installation works, it's graphic and simple:

[linux ati catalyst driver](http://support.amd.com/fr/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)

regards,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling it again using this guide [Ubuntu Oneiric Installation Guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide), is the most complete guide available to users of ATI and different linux's distributions.